# How to avoid "ignoring duplicate publish" in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am publishing data in the `Meteor.startup()` function in one of my server files, like so:

```
Meteor.publish("allImages", function() {
  return ghI.find( {} );
});
```

This is fine the first time the app starts up. However, if I make an edit to my code and the app restarts, Meteor says: "*Ignoring duplicate publish*" for all my publications.  Maybe this is a totally harmless warning, but does anyone know how to check and see if a publication already exists?  Or some other way to avoid this?

Comment: You can't tell if the client has received the `ghI` collection?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to come back and update this.  My problem was, I was calling a server method that did the publish in the startup code on the client.  So every time I restarted the app in the browser, it called that publish function again.  Once I got rid of the that call from the client (and moved the publish to the server startup code) everything was fine.

Comment: I have the same problem, but when I remove the duplicate publish, it doesn´t find the collection on the other hand

Comment: You should post a question with some code.  There are a lot of users on here with extensive knowledge about pubs / subs.